# The directory '/home/junsukhaa/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to run the following commands:

```
conda create -n enerf python=3.8
conda activate enerf
pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I installed conda.
I activated enerf.
But when I run

```
pip install torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I get this error:

[image]

This is my first time using Linux. Are there other steps that should be done before running `pip install ~`?

I've tried using `sudo`, `pip3`, `sudo -H`, etc but couldn't solve the issue.

## EDIT

How do I close this thread? After saving more space, now I have different error messages. Should I just edit this thread? or create a new one?

Comment: The actual error is in red, you can ignore the yellow message